# how to do transition on images in css3

Tags: css, css-transitions

Okay I have these 4 images

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="image1" /></li>
    <li><img src="image2" /></li>
    <li><img src="image3" /></li>
    <li><img src="image4" /></li>
</ul>
```

I have learnt a bit about animation and tried to implement through this

```
 ul{
-webkit-animation-name: example; 
-webkit-animation-duration: 4s; 
animation-name: example;
animation-duration: 6s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes example {
0%   {background-image: 'image1';}
25%  {background-image: 'image2';}
50%  {background-image: 'image3';}
100% {background-image: 'image4';}
}


@keyframes example {
0%   {background-image: 'image1';}
25%  {background-image: 'image2';}
50%  {background-image: 'image3';}
100% {background-image: 'image4';}
}
```

I am confused that how to make them work or images? I tried a bit of my work to do it but it doesn't work no images are being shown.

Comment: Looks like just a case of not enclosing the `background-image` url in `url(' ')`.  http://codepen.io/pjabbott/pen/jyEemw

Comment: Even If I do it in a div! Images won't change. it doesn't work I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to happen, though I do know that animate a background image work when setup properly.

Note that the element, a `div` in this case, has to have a height as it does not size itself to the background image's size.

Also, one need to use the proper syntax, `background-image: url(image-path-and-name)`

*Note, this appear to only work in Chrome though (didn't check with iOS/Safari)*

```css
div {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-animation-name: example; 
  -webkit-animation-duration: 12s; 
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 12s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes example {
  0% { background-image: url(http://placehold.it/150/f00); }
 25% { background-image: url(http://placehold.it/150/ff0); }
 50% { background-image: url(http://placehold.it/150/00f); }
100% { background-image: url(http://placehold.it/150/0f0); }
}
@keyframes example {
  0% { background-image: url(http://placehold.it/150/f00); }
 25% { background-image: url(http://placehold.it/150/ff0); }
 50% { background-image: url(http://placehold.it/150/00f); }
100% { background-image: url(http://placehold.it/150/0f0); }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Firefox and chrome

Comment: @Wayne I tested in both + Edge and they all work ... even here at SO ... and so does the fiddle I linked

Comment: Strange, `background-image` property is declared as **not** animatable, but it works. Amazing!

Comment: @VasilyLiaskovsky I am too ... also told it did work in FF and Edge though it does not ... in my version of Chrome which I use when on SO it does!!!